# Retrofit GET call from singleton class return list with size 0 at first

Tags: android, list, singleton, retrofit, retrofit2

I am working on an app in I have to use a certain type of data in many activities. so what I tried to do is I made singleton class and define my GET method there say `getProductHeads`, this is retrofit call returns a list to my activity where I calls it.

The problem I am facing is for the very first time when I start the app---> start my add product activity --- which calls this method `getProductHeads` return a list with 0 size and when I try to do it again by going back and starting the activity again it gives me data and it keeps on giving data until the app restarts.

I am a bit new to this and unable to get this I have checked over it but can't find much. Below is my singleton and where call that method code.

```
public class ProductHeads {

    private static ProductHeads mInstance;
    public  List<ProductHeadsModel> productHeadsModels = new ArrayList<ProductHeadsModel>();

    public static ProductHeads getInstance() {
        if(mInstance == null) {
            if (mInstance == null)
                mInstance = new ProductHeads();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private ProductHeads() {
//        productHeadsModels = new ArrayList<ProductHeadsModel>();
    }

    public  List<ProductHeadsModel> getProductHeads(String licenskey, Context context){

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<List<ProductHeadsModel>> call = requestInterface.getProductHeads(licenskey);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProductHeadsModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductHeadsModel>> call, Response<List<ProductHeadsModel>> response) {
                productHeadsModels = response.body();
                if (productHeadsModels != null){

                }else Toast.makeText(context, "No Product head response found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductHeadsModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Product Heads::::"+t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return this.productHeadsModels;
    }
}
```

I call it like this from my activity .....

```
 private List<ProductHeadsModel> productHeadsModels;
productHeadsModels = ProductHeads.getInstance().getProductHeads(mlicenseID, AddProduct.this);
```

I don't know if my approach is bad or what the problem is. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!!!!

::::EDIT:::::
here is my first time response data which appears alright but the list which is returned is empty

> 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL:
>   Product Shap 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app
>   E/CALL CALL: Color 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011
>   4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: Finish Type 2019-11-04
>   13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: Create Date
>   2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL:
>   Designer 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app
>   E/CALL CALL: Supervisor 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011
>   4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: Price 2019-11-04
>   13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: Stock Qty
>   2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL:
>   Quality 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app
>   E/CALL CALL: Alias Code 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011
>   4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: Comment 2019-11-04
>   13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: CBM 2019-11-04
>   13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: Weight
>   2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: CFT
>   2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: 
>   Loadability 20' 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011 4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app
>   E/CALL CALL: Loadability 40' 2019-11-04 13:38:03.011
>   4153-4153/com.ht.dell.qr_app E/CALL CALL: Loadability 40'HC

Comment: First of all never put retrofit instance, in singleton and print the response you get when a first time request is made and show it here.

Comment: yes i have checked it, during 1st attempt  productHeadsModels = response.body(); is getting data but return list is 0

Comment: What's the purpose of singleton class? each time that you call `getProductHeads` you are creating a new instance of  okHttpClient and Retrofit, which is so wired.

Comment: I am not getting it cause you get the data, but what is list here? You better add your first response in your question

Comment: @MohammadSianaki i have it sorted my retrofit instances but my main purpose for this it to get data using this function in multiple activities

Comment: @KaushikBurkule i am posting my first time response

Comment: There is no need for adding retrofit in the singleton class to access from multiple activities. Just make a single class and call it anytime, anywhere you want.

Comment: So, just to prevent multiple API call you made a singleton. right?

Comment: @KaushikBurkule yes right i have made a seperate apiservice class for this

Comment: @MohammadSianaki yes

Comment: You shouldn't use singleton for this purpose, just make an API call form your activity, then pass the response between activities by using `Bundle` **or** save the response in database and read it whenever you want

Comment: @KaushikBurkule added my first time response data

Comment: okay! i get your point but can you tell me what i am doing wrong here @MohammadSianaki

Comment: Oh man!  I think I figured out what are you doing wrong here. You are just returning the list before the response is fetched.

Comment: Because you are returning the list while, response has not come yet due to it's asynchronous nature!

Comment: You better enqueue your request from activity.

Comment: yes that' what i thought, list is getting returened before the response has arrived .... but why its working fine in 2nd 3rd attempts..?? @MohammadSianaki @ Kaushik Burkule

Comment: You are getting old response for each request you made that what i think